# Можно ли хранить id в поле json MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица **`slide_data`**

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                                                                                                                        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned                                                                                                            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| slide_id | bigint(20) unsigned                                                                                                         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data     | json                                                                                                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type     | varchar(255)                                                                                                                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| layer_id | bigint(20) unsigned                                                                                                         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| variable | varchar(255)                                                                                                                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Я хочу хранить в поле **`data`** json с ид другой таблици `{ products: [ 1, 3, 5, 8 ] }`. Правильно так делать? Или в поле типа json нельзя писать ид, других записей?

Comment: JSON-у всё равно, что он хранит, для него это просто именованные параметры. Вот только для FK значения из JSON использовать не получится.

Comment: @Akina FK ? Это что такое?

Comment: FK == Foreign Key. Внешний ключ.